# Why is "be" used in "Figuring out a vacation policy be particularly hard when you have employees around the world"?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I see the following sentence in [this article](https://qz.com/work/1402886/the-startup-behind-todoist-has-a-novel-new-vacation-policy/)

> Figuring out a vacation policy be particularly hard when you have
>   employees around the world.

Is putting "be" as the main verb grammatically correct? I thought the verb should be "is" instead but is there a special rule which allows "be" to be put there?

Comment: I gave it a cursory look and it appears to be a typo. I think the sentence should say: *Figuring out a vacation policy **can** be particularly hard when you have employees around the world.*

Comment: @MichaelRybkin That makes sense. Thanks a lot. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer so that I can mark it an accepted one?

Comment: Unless the writer was trying to [talk like a pirate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cKCkbWDGwE), it's a typo.  Or, as a pirate would say, *Arr matey -- it **be** a typo.*

Comment: @Andrew lol. I bought [the talk like a pirate T-shirt](https://www.cafepress.com/talklikeapirate.1815700232). It arrived a few days ago and I cannot wait for [Sep 19th](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Talk+Like+a+Pirate+Day&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) next year!

Comment: @fbessho  Well, shiver me timbers! Ye will be lookin' respendent in such sartorial finery,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a cursory look and it appears to be a typo. I think the sentence should be saying something like this:

> Figuring out a vacation policy **can** be particularly hard when you have employees around the world.

The modal verb *can* fits best there as it seems to make the most sense in the given context.